# Let $T$ be diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}$. Show each projection $P_\lambda$ can be expressed as a polynomial of powers $T^j$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T$ be diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}$ with a spectral decomposition
>   $$
> T = \sum_{\lambda \in sp(T)} \lambda P_\lambda
> $$
>   where $P_\lambda$ is the projection onto the eigenspace $E_\lambda(T)$. Show that for each projection $P_\lambda$, there is a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ such that $P_\lambda$ is a linear combination of powers $f(T) = \sum_{j=0} c_jT^j$.

Using the representation for $T$ above, we have
$$
f(T) 
= \sum_j c_j (\sum_\lambda \lambda^j P_\lambda) 
= \sum_\lambda \sum_j c_j P_\lambda^j 
= \sum_\lambda f(P_\lambda).
$$

But I don't think this gets any closer to expressing $P_\lambda$ in powers $T^j$. I'm still not even convinced that what the question is asking is possible.

Comment: Hint: If $T$ is diagonalizable, $x-\lambda$ and $g(x)=p(x)/(x-\lambda)$, where $p(x)$ is $T$’s minimal polynomial, are relatively prime. So, there exist polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ such that $a(x)g(x)+b(x)(x-\lambda)=1$.

Comment: @amd Thanks that's helpful. Obviously, if $P_\lambda(v) = v_\lambda$, I can see that $v_\lambda \in \ker b(T)(T-\lambda)$. After a few calculations, it's clear to me that $a(T)g(T)$ is the polynomial in powers of $T$ such that $a(T)g(T) = P_\lambda$. I suspect this is your conclusion as well?

Comment: Yes, that’s the basic idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(T)}\lambda P_{\lambda}$, where
$$
        I=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(T)}P_{\lambda},\\
              P_{\lambda}^2 = P_{\lambda} \\
                  P_{\lambda}P_{\mu} = 0,\;\; \lambda\ne \mu
$$
Then,
$$
          (T-\mu I)=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(T)}(\lambda-\mu)P_{\lambda}
$$
If $\mu$ is equal to some $\lambda\in\sigma(T)$, then the term involving $P_{\lambda}$ does not appear on the right. Therefore, you can eliminate all but one projection in the following way:
$$
              \prod_{\mu\in\sigma(T),\;\mu\ne\lambda}(T-\mu I)=\left(\prod_{\mu\in\sigma(T),\;\mu\ne\lambda}(\lambda-\mu)\right)P_{\lambda} \\
       P_{\lambda} = \frac{1}{\prod_{\mu\in\sigma(T),\;\mu\ne\lambda}(\lambda-\mu)}\prod_{\mu\in\sigma(T),\;\mu\ne\lambda}(T-\mu I)
$$
These are the Lagrange interpolating polynomials:
$$
       P_{\lambda}=p_{\lambda}(T),\;\;\;\mbox{ where } p_{\lambda}(x) = \frac{\prod_{\mu\in\sigma(T),\;\mu\ne\lambda}(x-\mu)}{\prod_{\mu\in\sigma(T),\;\mu\ne\lambda}(\lambda-\mu)}
$$

Comment: I would not have thought of this. The approach in the comments was more in line with what I've learned. Thank you for showing me something new. Is there an intuitive explanation of why the Lagrange interpolating polynomials appear here or their relationship to the projections of a finite dimensional vector space?

Comment: @mathjacks : One interesting application: If the minimal polynomial for a matrix has no repeated roots, then you can use the Lagrange polynomials to show that $p_{\lambda}(T)$ is a projection, that $p_{\lambda}(T)p_{\mu}(T)=0$ for $\lambda\ne \mu$, and then $(T-\lambda I)p_{\lambda}(T)=0$. This becomes an abstract way to diagonalize any linear operator (any dimension) that has such a minimal polynomial. It even works with the Fourier transform because $\mathcal{F}^4=I$. So the Fourier transform is diagonalized with eigenvalues $1,i,-1,-i$, and the eigenfunctions are Hermite functions.

Comment: @mathjacks : The intuition. A complex square matrix $T$ is diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial has no repeated factors. You can see why removing one of the factors, say $T-\lambda_kI$ gives you an expression whose range is annihilated by $T-\lambda_k I$, which means the range consists of eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda_k$. Knowing that you have a minimal polynomial allows you to show that the Lagrange polynomials applied to $T$ give you projections, and you can see right away they're disjoint, too, from the minimal polynomial.